# How navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition gets location coordinates of a client browser

Tags: javascript, browser, geolocation, navigator

I am using browser API for geolocation like below (codes written below are just for demo)

### Client Script using jQuery

```
       $(function () {
            $('#link-getlocation').click(function () {

                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(loc){
                       alert(loc.coords.latitude + ', ' + loc.coords.longitude);
                });                    
            });
        });
```

### Html

```
<a href="javascript:" id="link-getlocation">Get Location</a>
```

### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/yhHnD/1/

My question is how browser detects the location coordinates of the user

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the capabilities of the client browser.

- If the device running the browser has GPS (f.ex. a mobile phone), it generally uses GPS based locating
- If the device is on a WLAN, the browser can utilize WLAN location data (eg. via Google Location Services)
- Otherwise it most likely will use a GeoIP database

Most of these depend on OS and browser support and can vary between browsers.

Comment: So on a laptop it generally locates the source of the wireless network rather than your actual location?

Comment: From what I understand usually WLAN locating involves analyzing the signal strength of all the access points visible to you. Then, if the AP's coordinates are known, your location can be estimated as well. The accuracy of this can vary quite a lot, but it's usually still way more accurate than a Geo IP database.